# Navigation Controller is nil, though embedded in a view controller

Tags: ios, swift, uinavigationcontroller, storyboard, popviewcontroller

[image: Storyboard]

As you can see, my navigation controller is embedded in the root view controller. In this view controller, I have a subview, and at one point, I push the popover onto the view controller. For some reason, I cannot use `navigationController.popViewController(animated: true)` because the navigation controller is nil(by printing the value to the debug console). How can I fix this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [`dismiss(animated flag: Bool, completion: (() -> Void)? = nil)`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uiviewcontroller/1621505-dismiss). Call it from your popover view controller:

```
self.dismiss(animated: true)
```

Answer (score 0):

if you present your popover from ViewController

```
self.present(popover, animated: true, completion: nil)
```

you can dismiss it in popover

```
self.dismiss(animated: true)
```

and if you push your popover to your navigation controller by

```
self.navigationController?.pushViewController(popover, animated: true)
```

you can dismiss your popover using

```
self.navigationController?.popViewController(animated: true)
```